# Creating a xml file to store data local c# and read data from that created file

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to store data that i get from a url into a xml file and show that data when there is no internet.

I have this:

```
 async Task CreateSaveFile()
    {
        // Create document
        XDocument xmlDocument = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("Objects", from test in TestList
                                  select new XElement("test",
                                      new XElement("name", test.Name),
                                      new XElement("number", test.Number))));

        // Storage Folder
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        string fileName = "test.xml";
        StorageFile file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        Stream stream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();

        // Write file
        xmlDocument.Save(stream);
        stream.Flush();
    }
```

And this method to get the data from the created test.xml into a list:

```
 private List<Test> testList = new List<Test>();
 async Task<List<Test>> getTestList()
    {
        StorageFolder folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();


        foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
        // Get xml files
        XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(file.Path);

        // Get TestObjects
        testList = (from element in xmlFile.Root.Descendants("test")
                       select new Player(
                           element.Element("name").Value,
                           element.Element("number").Value)).ToList<Test>();

        }

        return testList;
    }
```

I get this error An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll‏

```
 public RelayCommand LoadedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(async () =>
            {
                await CreateSaveFile();
                try
                { 
                    TestList = await getTestList();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); throw;
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the full `ToString()` output of the [exception](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.targetinvocationexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) including the `InnerException`?

Comment: I mean what I said.  Either temporarily catch the exception with a `try {  } catch (Exception ex) { Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString(); throw; }` to see the full exception, or [break when the exception is thrown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d14azbfh.aspx) and [copy the exception to the clipboard](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/10/23/the-exception-assistant-vstipdebug0030.aspx).  Then let us know what it is.

Comment: It just go to the debug handler private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
                Debugger.Break();
            }
        }

Comment: `ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs` has a property `ExceptionObject`.  Please try to add the output of `Debug.WriteLine(e.ExceptionObject.ToString())` to your question.

Comment: The problem is that im not a .Net expert tbh and that i don't really have an idea where or how :)

Comment: Try doing what I suggested.  Bracket all the code in `CreateSaveFile()` and `getTestList()` with a `try { } catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); }` as is shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xtd0s8kd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: ok i got this Cannot open 'file:///C:/Data/Users/DefApps/AppData/{86388A9B-8A3E-46B8-A240-9413ECDFE7AA}/local/test.xml'. The Uri parameter must be a relative path pointing to content inside the Silverlight application's XAP package. If you need to load content from an arbitrary Uri, please see the documentation on Loading XML content using WebClient/HttpWebRequest.

Comment: I don't know how to solve that, it's a Silverlight problem not an XML problem.  [Tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions) it [tag:silverlight], and include the *complete traceback and exception text* in the question, and a Silverlight expert may be able to help.

Comment: ok thank you for the try catch error message anyway!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like the process for windows store apps, Silverlight has a different api. See this [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc265154(v=vs.95).aspx) for reading and writing to Silverlight isolated storage.